# Firebase Realtime Chat Rules

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I made a chat application using firebase realtime database. Users can send private messages to each other. How should the rules part be? I keep getting emails from Firebase that the rules are not reliable.

This is my firebase Collections:

[image]

This is my firebase Rules:

[image]

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth.uid!=null",
    ".write": "auth.uid!=null",
  }
}
```

Comment: This one is alright.

Comment: The rules that you have mean any authenticated user has read and write access to everything in the database. So for a chat application this means any authenticated user can access other users' chats, which compromises users' privacy. You should write fine-tuned rules that limit users to access only the chats they are meant for them.

Comment: Yes I am aware. How can I do the settings you mentioned? can you help me?

Comment: The rules dependend on how you have structured your database. If you can share how your database is structured I can write you a sample rules that work.

Comment: I made some changes and put the things that the other users should not see and the passwords admin-users but I could not write the rules.
So what I want to do is that the opposing users see nothing in admin-users. so they can see their own chats and other person's profile info

Realtime looks like this right now: 
https://i.hizliresim.com/byl6n82.jpg

Comment: Please update the question to include the database structure graphic, to provide adequate context.

Comment: @wambada I am waiting for news from you

Comment: @AsımOdabaş did you understand my answer?

Answer (score 0):

**Only an authenticated admin user can read and write their own admin-user** data:

```
{
  "rules": {
     "admin-users": {
        "$userId": {
          ".read" : "auth.uid === $userId",
          ".write": "auth.uid === $userId"
        }
     }
   }
 }
```

Or:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "admin-users": {
      "$user": {
        ".read" : "data.child('userUid').val() === auth.uid",
        ".write": "data.child('userUid').val() === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

1. **An authenticated user can read all data under Users.**
2. **An authenticated user can can only update their own data except the 'userUid' field. Can only update the 'userUid' field if it is a new document creation ('!data.exists()') e.g when it is a signup/register.**
3. **An authenticated admin can read and write all the data in Users including the 'userUid' field.**

   ```
   {
   "rules": {
       "users": {
           ".read": "auth !== null",
           "$userId": {
               "userId": {
                   ".write": "root.child('admin-users').child(auth.uid).exists() || !data.exists()"
               },
               "$other_fields": {
                   ".write": "$userId === auth.uid || root.child('admin-users').child(auth.uid).exists()"
               }
           }
       }
   }}
   ```
4. **Only Admins can read and write everything in under Chats**
5. **Authenticated users can read chat messages in which their userUid matches either 'senderId' or 'receiverId'**
6. **Authenticated users can write/update a message only if their userUid matches 'senderId'.**

   ```
    {
    "rules": {
        "chats": {
            ".read": "root.child('admin-users').hasChild(auth.uid)",
            ".write": "root.child('admin-users').hasChild(auth.uid)",
            "$chat": {
                "$message": {
                    ".read": "auth !== null && data.child('receiverId').val() === auth.uid || data.child('senderId').val() === auth.uid",
                    ".write": "auth !== null && !data.exists() || data.child('senderId').val() === auth.uid"
                }
            }
        }
    }}
   ```

These sample rules are just to give guidance on how security rules work. You can create different rules that can work as well with your use case. See link for more details https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/insecure-rules
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/core-syntax